# How to create command in bash to compile multiple C program with multiple flags

Tags: c, makefile, zsh

So my file structure is basically this -

- I have a .zshrc file since I'm on OS X
- I have a .my_custom_commands.sh file which contains the shortcuts I want
- In my .zshrc I source the commands file

Currently, I'm looking for a solution to compile multiple files with flags using the "gcc" command

For example, if I want to compile a.c and b.c

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic -o output.c a.c b.c
```

However, I don't want to type this out every time, so I was thinking there would be a way to create a custom command say 'gccf' (gcc flags). The thing is that I don't know zsh programming language so I'm just wondering if there is a way to pass multiple args into the function I created in the commands file.

I have something like this right now

```
function gccf() {
    gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic -o output.c $1 $2
}
```

I understand that the args you pass into the command line are represented by $1, $2..., but is there anyway to check how many args have been passed? Because if $2 isn't passed then this won't work I think.

Comment: Look into the `CFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` environment variables, or into `make` if it's the build you want to automate.

Comment: Thank you @Jens! The $@ works perfectly in my bash file. Seems like ```make``` is the correct approach, so I'll look into that as well.

Comment: Ok, I've made it an answer. The next step is to upvote all answers you found helpful, and after a while when no new answers are given, accept the one that helped you most (if there is one).

Comment: @ujjain : You can use `$@` in zsh as well. The main difference is, that while in bash you have to write it as `"$@"`, you can in zsh omit in this case the double quotes.

Comment: @ujjain : Maybe you can also clarify, why you mention _bash_ in the title of your question, but refer to _zsh_ in the question itself and in your tags.

Answer (score 2):

Set CFLAGS as you want and just use the default rules for make.  You don't even need a makefile:

```
$ rm -f Makefile
$ ls a.c
a.c
$ make a
cc   a.c   -o a
$ rm -f a.o a
$ export CFLAGS=-pedantic
$ make a
cc -pedantic    a.c   -o a
```

If you have multiple source files, you'll need a (trivial) makefile:

```
$ rm -f a *.o output Makefile
$ unset CFLAGS
$ make a
cc   a.c   -o a
$ export CFLAGS='-Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic'
$ rm a; make a
cc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic    a.c   -o a
$ printf 'output: a.o b.o\n\t$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)\n' > Makefile
$ make output
cc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic   -c -o a.o a.c
cc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic   -c -o b.o b.c
cc  a.o b.o -o output 
$ rm -rf *.o output
$ export CC=gcc LDLIBS=-lm
$ make output
gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic   -c -o a.o a.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic   -c -o b.o b.c
gcc  a.o b.o -o output  -lm
```

In other words, don't try to reinvent the wheel.  Your use case has been encountered by many people, and there are long standing conventions and tools in place to enable the work flow.

Note that you may want to include `LOADLIBES` along with `LDLIBS`, but the former name should (probably?) no longer be used.

Answer (score 1):

In Bourne-heritage shells (e.g. sh, zsh, bash, ksh), to specify all arguments passed to a program or function, use `"$@"` (including the double quotes!), which expands to any number of args passed, including none.

But if you follow the Unix philosophy of using the one tool that does just one thing, you want to look at `make` as suggested in comments and other answers.

PS: you also want `-o output`, not `-o output.c`, since your program is not a C source file, but an executable.